# SSIS EXECUTE SQL TASK BULK INSERT ERROR

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, ssis, ssis-2008

when trying to import a small text file into a table using ssis package(EXECUTE SQL TASK) got the below mentioned error

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "sp_import_pkg2010 ?,?,?" failed with the following error: "Could not bulk insert because file 'K:\Data\Usa\Prov.txt' could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(error not found).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

There is no connection problem ,also the file 'K:\Data\Usa\Prov.txt'  does exist and can open

Comment: I guess `K:` drive is a mapped network drive. Try to copy this txt file and load it from `C:` drive. In this case SSIS is running under different account (not current logged user) so it doesn't know what `K:` drive is.

Comment: yes K drive is a mpped drive..but is there any way to do this iin K drive itself..the thingg is it has been accessed by different users.So I can not copied to c drive

Comment: try to change path to `\\SERVER\PATH\Data\Usa\Prov.txt` instead of `K:\`

Comment: yes initially it was under the full path like \\SERVER\PATH\Data\Usa\Prov.txt ....but it was giving some "can not opened issue" I have moved it under the mapped drive K..but again no luck

Comment: actually there 2 execute sql task i nthe package.Both using same stored procedure with different parameters(different file names on same location).The first task import file 1 and the second task imports file2..when i changed to the server path \\ server then one fo the tasks succeded and the other failed ..

Comment: the failed task  ssis error log is as shown below Error: OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'STREAM' IRowset::GetNextRows returned 0x80004005:  The provider did not give any information about the error.].

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "sp_import_2010 ?,?,?" failed with the following error: "The statement has been terminated.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.